# SELF JOIN vs LEFT JOIN performance in FireBird

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

To increase the speed of different queries run against a Firebird 2.5 database from a Delphi XE win32 application, which are the faster:

- self joins - for example

  SELECT e1.full_name AS Employee, e2.full_name AS Manager
   FROM employee e1 JOIN employee e2
   ON e1.mng_id = e2.emp_no;

OR

- left joins with other table

  SELECT e1.full_name AS Employee, e2.full_name AS Manager
   FROM employee e1 
   LEFT JOIN employee_info e2
   ON e1.mng_id = e2.emp_no;

taking in consideration that tables concerned will contain more than 50k rows, and I will add indexes in order to speed up the queries as much as I can.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Delphi, as the query itself is processed on the server. Removing the Delphi tag.

Comment: you're right. Now, I wait the answer from the Firebird guys, even guys from 'Delphi' are using it a lot, and probably got/had the same question.

Comment: There is no right answer without knowing the PLAN used by each query.

Answer (score 0):

to increase speed of a query, you need to create a index by all fields that are involved on WHERE clause